# Problema en JAVA Swing: Como solucionar este problema: "Class not found: javax.swing.JPanel"

Tags: java, java-swing, jpanel

Como solucionar este problema: "Class not found: javax.swing.JPanel"

Comment: Con la información provista no pude reproducir el error.

Comment: Buenas, Nelfer, bienvenido al sitio. Normalmente para programar en Java se usa un IDE como IntelliJ o Eclipse. La instalación de dichos IDE suele detectar donde tienes instalado tu JDK en el ordenador. Hace muchísimo tiempo que el paquete javax.swing viene instalado de serie en esa JDK, es decir, contiene esa clase JPanel. Por tanto, probablemente no hayas instalado correctamente tu IDE. Verifica donde está tu JDK y si lo tienes bien enlazado en el IDE.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.